# Is there a way to have a private class method inherit from a public interface method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, interface

I'd like to have something like this:

```
public interface IBlah
{
   void setBlah();
   float calculateBlahVelocity();
}


public class Blah : IBlah
{
   private void setBlah() { /** .... **/ }
   public float calculateBlahVelocity { /** .... **/ }
}
```

But C# doesn't seem to like that. So is there a[nother] way to get this sort of functionality?

Comment: Why? Anything implementing an interface is inherently accessible.  (but see explicit interface implementations, and beware of casts)

Comment: @SLaks - if there's a way or another way to do this (ie. not using interfaces), i'm more than happy to know about it. just to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly*.  If `Blah` implements `IBlah` then it must have a `setBlah` method.

You *can*, however, *explicitly* implement the method, which forces callers to use the method *through* the `IBlah` interface:

```
public class Blah : IBlah
{
   void IBlah.setBlah() { /** .... **/ }
   public float calculateBlahVelocity() { /** .... **/ }
}
```

Then calls to the method will need to be done through the interface:

```
Blah b = new Blah();
b.setBlah();  // invalid
IBlah i = b;
i.setBlah();  // valid
```

Comment: This is the right answer with the note that the explicit implementation is private as asked, which is left out from the answer.